# Trouble with parsing source html with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parsing, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to use nokogiri to select a DOM element but it seems to be returning an empty array.

I run this code:

```
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://twitter.com/#!/ladygaga"))
```

and it returns the whole source code parsed by Nokogiri.

However, when I run

```
doc.css(".stream-tweet")
```

it returns an empty array. `.stream-tweet` is a class for multiple div elements at `http://twitter.com/#!/ladygaga` that I found by inspecting the source code.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no `div` element with `stream-tweet` class if you look at `doc`.
That div loads afterwards with AJAX request to twitter api.

Comment: is there a way to make `doc` formated better? Also what exactly do you mean by "Actual div loads afterwards via javascript twitter api."

Comment: there is no way to do this with nokogiri, because nokogiri can't parse result of ajax request. why do you need it? probably you can use twitter api.

Comment: @Justin What NARKOZ means is that if you "View Source" (and don't Inspect Element), you will see that the HTML you claim exists does not exist in the original HTTP response for that URL. Instead, JavaScript code runs on the site and eventually receives content from one of 11 (!) different XHR JSON requests it makes. The JavaScript then dynamically builds elements on the page with the classes. Nokogiri is not a full web browser and does not run JavaScript.

Comment: @Phrogz ahhhh ok that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Justin Look up "headless browser". See also [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) and [Johnson](https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson) and [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

Answer (score 1):

@NARKOZ has the correct answer to your question about why what you're trying to do isn't working. You should accept that answer.

To solve your problem, try this:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

gaga = JSON.parse(open('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=1&include_available_features=1&contributor_details=true&include_rts=true&user_id=14230524').read)

pp gaga.map{ |tweet| tweet['text'] }[0..3]

#=> ["Here's my LIVE radio performance on the Howard Stern Show! http://bit.ly/pighVL\"",
#=>  "Thanks baby. I'm a die hard monsterfan RT@GSp0nz: @ladygaga 's album speaks to me more than any other album ever.  #diehardfan",
#=>  "http://twitpic.com/5s4f2h - Just left @HowardStern, rockers with long hair have a sweetspot for girls like me. He was a doll. :)",
#=>  "SURPRISE MONSTERS! You can find a link to a more readable format of my V Mag Pop Culture Column on http://t.co/ekIJBXo My new blog!"]
```

Here's what the whole JSON looks like as a Ruby Array of Hashes (truncated for Stack Overflow):

```rb
[{"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "following"=>true,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "listed_count"=>208144,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "lang"=>"en",
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781463,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "notifications"=>true,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Tue Jul 19 18:09:40 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "Here's my LIVE radio performance on the Howard Stern Show! http://bit.ly/pighVL\"",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"user_mentions"=>[],
    "urls"=>
     [{"url"=>"http://bit.ly/pighVL",
       "indices"=>[59, 79],
       "expanded_url"=>nil}],
    "hashtags"=>[]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"93382007496769536",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>93382007496769536},
 {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "following"=>true,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "lang"=>"en",
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781456,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "listed_count"=>208145,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg"},
  "created_at"=>"Tue Jul 19 17:51:11 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "Thanks baby. I'm a die hard monsterfan RT@GSp0nz: @ladygaga 's album speaks to me more than any other album ever.  #diehardfan",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"hashtags"=>[{"indices"=>[115, 126], "text"=>"diehardfan"}],
    "user_mentions"=>
     [{"name"=>"Lady Gaga",
       "indices"=>[50, 59],
       "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
       "id_str"=>"14230524",
       "id"=>14230524}],
    "urls"=>[]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"93377358974812161",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>93377358974812161},
 {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "listed_count"=>208144,
    "following"=>false,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "lang"=>"en",
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781392,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Mon Jul 18 14:30:46 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "http://twitpic.com/5s4f2h - Just left @HowardStern, rockers with long hair have a sweetspot for girls like me. He was a doll. :)",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"hashtags"=>[],
    "user_mentions"=>
     [{"name"=>"Howard Stern",
       "indices"=>[38, 50],
       "screen_name"=>"HowardStern",
       "id_str"=>"246481013",
       "id"=>246481013}],
    "urls"=>
     [{"url"=>"http://twitpic.com/5s4f2h",
       "indices"=>[0, 25],
       "expanded_url"=>nil}]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"92964531315294209",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>92964531315294209},
 {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "following"=>true,
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "listed_count"=>208146,
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "lang"=>"en",
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781425,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Mon Jul 18 11:24:18 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "SURPRISE MONSTERS! You can find a link to a more readable format of my V Mag Pop Culture Column on http://t.co/ekIJBXo My new blog!",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"user_mentions"=>[],
    "urls"=>
     [{"url"=>"http://t.co/ekIJBXo",
       "display_url"=>"tinyurl.com/3p42npn",
       "indices"=>[99, 118],
       "expanded_url"=>"http://tinyurl.com/3p42npn"}],
    "hashtags"=>[]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>"web",
  "id_str"=>"92917605253386241",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>92917605253386241},
 {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "following"=>false,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "lang"=>"en",
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781014,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "listed_count"=>208145,
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Mon Jul 18 10:35:37 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "http://twitpic.com/5s1f29 - If you need a quick fashion read, here's my V Mag column for the month. This time we did a Triptych!",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"hashtags"=>[],
    "user_mentions"=>[],
    "urls"=>
     [{"url"=>"http://twitpic.com/5s1f29",
       "indices"=>[0, 25],
       "expanded_url"=>nil}]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"92905355444621313",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>92905355444621313},
 {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "following"=>true,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "listed_count"=>208145,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "lang"=>"en",
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11780972,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Sun Jul 17 22:50:49 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "I'm live with @howardstern 2moro morning on Sirius XM. Big fan. Gonna sing  my face off, and talk shit w the raddest Hair in radio. 8am EDT",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"hashtags"=>[],
    "user_mentions"=>
     [{"name"=>"Howard Stern",
       "indices"=>[14, 26],
       "screen_name"=>"HowardStern",
       "id_str"=>"246481013",
       "id"=>246481013}],
    "urls"=>[]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>false,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"92727984666066944",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>92727984666066944},
 {"retweeted_status"=>
   {"in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
    "user"=>
     {"time_zone"=>"Central Time (US & Canada)",
      "protected"=>false,
      "profile_image_url_https"=>
       "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1395256604/DSCN06191_normal.jpg",
      "location"=>"USA",
      "default_profile_image"=>false,
      "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
      "following"=>false,
      "geo_enabled"=>true,
      "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
      "name"=>"John Marshall",
      "contributors_enabled"=>false,
      "profile_background_color"=>"709397",
      "url"=>nil,
      "is_translator"=>false,
      "verified"=>false,
      "profile_background_image_url"=>
       "http://a1.twimg.com/images/themes/theme6/bg.gif",
      "utc_offset"=>-21600,
      "follow_request_sent"=>false,
      "statuses_count"=>849,
      "favourites_count"=>0,
      "created_at"=>"Mon Mar 07 03:52:21 +0000 2011",
      "friends_count"=>423,
      "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
      "profile_image_url"=>
       "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1395256604/DSCN06191_normal.jpg",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"A0C5C7",
      "description"=>
       "420 #BoardsofCanada #GLP #iamamiwhoami #M\u00FCtterMons\u2020re Say what you say, do what you do, feel what you feel, as long as it's real.",
      "lang"=>"en",
      "profile_background_tile"=>false,
      "followers_count"=>583,
      "screen_name"=>"Karczochy",
      "listed_count"=>5,
      "id_str"=>"261997342",
      "profile_link_color"=>"FF3300",
      "id"=>261997342,
      "default_profile"=>false,
      "notifications"=>false,
      "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
       "https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme6/bg.gif",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"86A4A6"},
    "created_at"=>"Sun Jul 17 21:36:45 +0000 2011",
    "geo"=>nil,
    "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
    "favorited"=>false,
    "text"=>
     "LOL. That's gonna be..interesting..RT @jeff1317 Howard Stern is back tomorrow and @ladygaga is a guest! Should make for great radio!",
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
    "entities"=>
     {"hashtags"=>[],
      "user_mentions"=>
       [{"name"=>"Jeff",
         "indices"=>[38, 47],
         "screen_name"=>"jeff1317",
         "id_str"=>"22542097",
         "id"=>22542097},
        {"name"=>"Lady Gaga",
         "indices"=>[82, 91],
         "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
         "id_str"=>"14230524",
         "id"=>14230524}],
      "urls"=>[]},
    "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
    "place"=>nil,
    "coordinates"=>nil,
    "truncated"=>false,
    "source"=>
     "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPad</a>",
    "id_str"=>"92709349004279809",
    "contributors"=>nil,
    "retweeted"=>false,
    "retweet_count"=>"100+",
    "id"=>92709349004279809},
  "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil,
  "user"=>
   {"time_zone"=>"Quito",
    "protected"=>false,
    "profile_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "location"=>"New York, NY",
    "default_profile_image"=>false,
    "show_all_inline_media"=>false,
    "following"=>false,
    "geo_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_use_background_image"=>true,
    "name"=>"Lady Gaga",
    "contributors_enabled"=>false,
    "profile_background_color"=>"9AE4E8",
    "url"=>"http://www.ladygaga.com",
    "is_translator"=>false,
    "verified"=>true,
    "profile_background_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "utc_offset"=>-18000,
    "follow_request_sent"=>false,
    "statuses_count"=>968,
    "favourites_count"=>2,
    "created_at"=>"Wed Mar 26 22:37:48 +0000 2008",
    "friends_count"=>142497,
    "profile_text_color"=>"333333",
    "profile_image_url"=>
     "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1239447061/Unnamed-1_normal.jpg",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDFFCC",
    "description"=>"mother mons\u2020er\r\n",
    "lang"=>"en",
    "profile_background_tile"=>true,
    "followers_count"=>11781095,
    "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
    "listed_count"=>208145,
    "id_str"=>"14230524",
    "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4",
    "id"=>14230524,
    "default_profile"=>false,
    "notifications"=>false,
    "profile_background_image_url_https"=>
     "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/203383875/Unnamed-1.jpg",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"BDDCAD"},
  "created_at"=>"Sun Jul 17 21:38:16 +0000 2011",
  "geo"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id"=>nil,
  "favorited"=>false,
  "text"=>
   "RT @Karczochy: LOL. That's gonna be..interesting..RT @jeff1317 Howard Stern is back tomorrow and @ladygaga is a guest! Should make for g ...",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil,
  "entities"=>
   {"hashtags"=>[],
    "user_mentions"=>
     [{"name"=>"John Marshall",
       "indices"=>[3, 13],
       "screen_name"=>"Karczochy",
       "id_str"=>"261997342",
       "id"=>261997342},
      {"name"=>"Jeff",
       "indices"=>[53, 62],
       "screen_name"=>"jeff1317",
       "id_str"=>"22542097",
       "id"=>22542097},
      {"name"=>"Lady Gaga",
       "indices"=>[97, 106],
       "screen_name"=>"ladygaga",
       "id_str"=>"14230524",
       "id"=>14230524}],
    "urls"=>[]},
  "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>nil,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>nil,
  "place"=>nil,
  "coordinates"=>nil,
  "truncated"=>true,
  "source"=>
   "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry\u00AE</a>",
  "id_str"=>"92709727896735745",
  "contributors"=>nil,
  "retweeted"=>false,
  "retweet_count"=>"100+",
  "id"=>92709727896735745},
```

Comment: @Justin How about you explain what you're trying to do. What CSS styling do you want? Are you trying to spoof Twitter appearance and markup yourself?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to frame the site lol. I don't think they allow it though (they bust any iframes with javascript), and I'm trying to find a way around it.